# Compute matrix based on logical expression

Tags: r

I need to compute a matrix base on a logical expression.

I have a matrix called A and a matrix called B:

```
A=matrix(c(1,1,1,1),nrow=2,ncol=2)
B=matrix(c(2,2,2,2),nrow=2,ncol=2)
```

Based on whether a variable called lambda is equal to one, I want to compute a matrix C, which is equal to A. On the other hand, if lambda is equal to zero, the matrix C should be equal to the matrix B. It should look something like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
C=ifelse(lambda==1,A,B)
```

Thanks.

Comment: `if(lambda == 1) A else B`.

Comment: `C <- (lambda==1)*A + (lambda!=1)*B`

Comment: This is a case for `if(){}else{}`, namely : `C=if( lambda==1 ){ A }else{ B }`

Comment: Read the paragraph labeled "Warning" in the help page for "ifelse"